# Angular Testing Stubs and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been following angular [testing guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) and set up one of my tests as follows

```
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
let activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteStub;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [
            {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: ActivatedRouteStub},
            {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub}
        ]
    });
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    activatedRoute = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    activatedRoute.testParams = { email: email};
    fixture.detectChanges(); // calls ngOnInit
});
```

where

```
@Injectable()
export class ActivatedRouteStub {
    // ActivatedRoute.params is Observable
    private subject = new BehaviorSubject(this.testParams);
    params = this.subject.asObservable();

    // Test parameters
    private _testParams: {};
    get testParams() { return this._testParams; }
    set testParams(params: {}) {
        this._testParams = params;
        this.subject.next(params);
    }

    // ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params
    get snapshot() {
        return { params: this.testParams };
    }
}
```

This was all transpiling fine until I performed an `npm install` to update packages (Angular 4 and typescript) and now I get the following errors

```
TS2322: Type 'ActivatedRoute' is not assignable to type 'ActivatedRouteStub'.
  Property 'subject' is missing in type 'ActivatedRoute'.

TS2339: Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRouteStub'.
```

Any ideas why I would suddenly be getting these errors?

Comment: I can't explain what changed (that probably depends on how old your previous versions of Angular and Typescript were). But the errors seem simple enough to fix: a) make the `subject` property of the stubbed class be a public variable, b) add the `parent` property to the stubbed class. However, I keep stumbling on better ways to write tests, you might look into getting rid of your stubbed class and use the `RouterTestingModule`. Just a guess, in case it makes your testing easier...

Comment: If you add: `imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],` to the testbed configuration instead of declaring the individual providers for `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` it might alleviate the need for stubs. Take that w/a grain of salt, I'm still wrapping my head around testing in Angular2 / Angular4.

Comment: @SunilD.  there is no `ActivatedRoute` stub in `RouterTestingModule`. Unfortauntely you are still forced to mock manually. See https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: The `ActivatedRouteStub` does not match the interface of the `ActivatedRoute` https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#parent. So it's not a complete stub.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is trying to retrieve an `ActivatedRoute` class, and assign in to `ActivatedRouteStub`. The fix is the followng:

```
let activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteStub;
 ...
activatedRoute = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ActivatedRoute) as any;
```